# Not collapse accordion of bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a `jsfiddle` for accordion [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/BhBHf/1/)

It has two colums left and right, whenever i try to collapse right accordion, and if it remains open and try to click on left accordion then the right accordion should close, How can It be ?

Comment: It will not solve your problem, but your two accordion has the same id's, which is not possible: all the id in a page must be unique.

Comment: If I have changed the id then how can I collapse the 2nd div

Comment: See my answer with the fiddle ;)

Comment: Hey guys, can anyone please explain me why I got so many downvotes for this question ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but i think you should had some code to your question ;)

Comment: but for code purpose I have used `jsfiddle`. these things are only for demotivation, downvote without any comment :(

Comment: Yes but the code you have in your fiddle can be way bigger than the code where the issue is. It's not the case here, but i advice you to always put a little piece of code to go with the fiddle ;)

Comment: Ok thanks Getz .. I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/BhBHf/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion .accordion-toggle').each(function () {
        $(this).html('<span class="plus">+</span>' + $(this).text());
    });
    $('.accordion a').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).children('.plus').text() === '+') {
            $(this).children('.plus').text('-');
            $(this).css({
                'color': 'red'
            });
            $('.accordion a').not(this).children('.plus').text('+');
            $('.accordion a').not(this).css({
                'color': '#666'
            });
            $('.in').collapse("hide").removeClass("in");
        } else {
            $(this).children('.plus').text('+');
            $(this).css({
                'color': '#666'
            });

        }
    });
});
```

I've also renamed your two accordion in HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

try js

http://jsfiddle.net/BhBHf/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .accordion-toggle').each(function(){
        $(this).html('<span class="plus">+</span>'+$(this).text());
    });
    $('.accordion a').on('click',function(){
        if($(this).children('.plus').text()==='+'){
            $(this).children('.plus').text('-');
            $(this).css({'color':'red'});
        }
        else{
            $(this).children('.plus').text('+');
            $(this).css({'color':'#666'});
        }
         $('.accordion').on('hide', function () {
        $('[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('accordion');
    });
    });

});
```